# Calculating a sum in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to know how to get a sum of values in a 3x3 `NumPy` array with a loop. 
For example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

The output should be `[6,15,24]`.

Comment: Check this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `np.array.sum` with `axis` argument as one:

```
arr.sum(1)
```

Example:

```
>>> arr=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> arr.sum(1)
array([ 6, 15, 24])
```

Or if it is a list:

```
np.sum(array,1)
```

Example:

```
>>> arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> np.sum(arr,1)
array([ 6, 15, 24])
>>>
```